# How can I change size of a 'uncommitted changes' region of view in vs code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image: uncommited changes]

It is my first time to see this view and I want to resize it..

I looked for a slider control near the view but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What plugin is this?

Comment: what size in what dimension? horizontally? vertically?

Comment: sorry, width, horizontally

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't notice it was from a plugin.. I will check it. It was from GitLense. I disabled it. Thank you!